# Excel Intermittently Crashes When Opening Network File / Enabling Content With User Defined Functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file stored on our network that houses part number requests.  This file is shared between two departments that, according to IT, are all up to date on 64-bit versions of Excel.

The file houses several simple user defined functions, such as ConcatUniq. 
The file will open and function properly for weeks at a time, and then randomly will either crash upon opening, or crash upon enabling content.  **We then rebuild the file from scratch, it will work for several weeks, then will crash again.**   These are widely used functions, and we don’t believe the functions themselves are causing the issues.

Additionally, a colleague had issues with the ConcatUniq function returning correct values on some lines, but returining #value errors on other lines. For this, I created a separate sheet with the ConcatUniq UDF, and a loop that sets cell formulas as the ConcatUniq function and allows the UDF to be stepped through, while printing each value in the range.

After saving and then sending this to a colleague to test, it crashed Excel upon opening.  Mine still opened fine, but crashed on enabling content.  This appears to be the bigger issue here, but nonetheless, sometimes the file crashes, sometimes it doesn’t, sometimes the UDF works, and sometimes it doesn’t.

We are unsure as to if this is a problem with Excel / Add-ons, our network/firewall paramaters, or the VBA itself.  I don’t believe this is any sort of compiler error, as the functions do work locally.  This problem seems to happen after these files are saved by users on the network.

I am hoping for some guidance regarding where to look for an issue causing these symptoms (Excel, network/firewall, VBA).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

As requested:

```
    Function ConcatUniq(ByRef rng As Range, _
    ByVal myJoin As String) As String
Dim r As Range
Static dic As Object
If dic Is Nothing Then _
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each r In rng
    dic(r.Value) = Empty
Next
ConcatUniq = Join$(dic.keys, myJoin)
dic.RemoveAll
End Function

'syntax = concatuniq(RANGE,"delimeter")
```

Comment: If you want us to look at your code that may be causing issues, please [edit] your question and add that code. If your issue is not related to specific code (which I assume to be the case with your _"we don’t believe the functions themselves are causing the issues"_ statement), then this should be posted to [su]. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing we can offer here without seeing the code.

Comment: Code added to original post, thanks!

Comment: That looks fine to me...   If the ranges passed in are always contiguous then you could maybe get a slight performance boost by reading the range value in a single operation, then looping over the resulting array to fill the dictionary.  To be on the safe side you could even check `rng.Areas.Count` to switch back to your original loop.  Might be worth checking each input cell for error values and skipping those if you want to avoid #VALUE outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

That's a simple enough solution to try regarding the #values.  The bigger problem here interrupting workflows is the breaking of the files that use this code, which i realize may be a coincidence.  Do you have any insight into this?

I'll probably take @K.Dᴀᴠɪs recommendation and post to SuperUser as well.

Comment: I don't have any insight on why your files "break" - I've only very rarely run into that problem, and only in workbooks with a lot of VBA which has been frequently revised/ added to.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out my comments above:

```
Function ConcatUniq(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal myJoin As String) As String
    Dim cl As Range, data, r As Long, c As Long, v
    Static dic As Object
    If dic Is Nothing Then Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        For Each cl In rng.Cells
            v = cl.Value
            If Not IsError(v) Then dic(v) = Empty
        Next
    Else
        data = rng.Value
        For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            v = data(r, c)
            If Not IsError(v) Then dic(v) = Empty
        Next c
        Next r
    End If
    ConcatUniq = Join$(dic.keys, myJoin)
    dic.RemoveAll
End Function
```

In my testing with a single-area range this is about twice as fast.

Comment: I implemented your changes here. However, Is there any reason this would work on my machine, but not another user's machine?   He's returning #value when using ConcatUniq.  He gave me control of his machine through MS Lync and I was able to step through the UDF by setting a random cell's formula using ConcatUniq.  Once stepping through, it exited the UDF after running "Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Comment: Are they on a Mac?  This code won't run there since there's no `CreateObject` - that's a Windows COM thing.  You can try this if you need cross-platform support:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Comment: They are not on a Mac.  This is why this is so strange. Apparently same version of Excel per IT, you open the file on my or another co-workers in my department's machine and it works fine. Opened from another departments machine, it errors out on creating a dictionary.

Comment: Is it only CreateObject on a dictionary which fails?  Can you use (eg) `CreateObject("Excel.Application") ` or `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` with no error?

Comment: I misspoke, It doesn't even fail. It simply exits the UDF function and goes straight to 'end sub' after running the 'Create Object' line.  I will try one of those and see what happens.